# fromCharCode equivalent in Power Query

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerquery

I have a list of values which I would like to convert in Power Query using an equivalent of JavaScript's **[String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)**.
Any help appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powerquery:

```
let Source = {189, 43, 190, 61},
convert = Text.Combine(List.Transform (Source, each Character.FromNumber(_)))
in convert
```

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/character-fromnumber